# masking in ENVI

Tags: landsat, ndvi, envi, masking, cloud-gis

I have surface reflectance generated NDVI which I got from ESPA interface, https://espa.cr.usgs.gov. How do I mask cloud with Qa band in ENVI?

Comment: Create a decision tree decoding BQA bit by bit